# How to make multiple spaces wrappable in html?

Tags: html, css, cpu-word, word-wrap

How can I insert multiple spaces between words in a div but still make it word wrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS property [white-space: pre-wrap;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to indicate to the browser that the contents of the element are pre-formatted (so should consider the whitespace significant and not remove it) and still line wrap.

```css
div {
    font-size: 26px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>This          is                   text                with                       spaces             that                wraps.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for all of the words in the `<div>` or if there's a good reason to put a `<span>` or something around the words you do need it for you could also try the css property [word-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing).

```
selector { 
    word-spacing: /*some length depending on your font*/
}
```